# how to show selected navbar item in another part of the same page

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

i have a menu in one side of laravel blade page , and other side of page i have a one div that i want to displayed selected item of navbar in this div .
my code in bellow:

```
<div class="col-1" style="position: fixed;z-index: 3;width: 11%; height:calc(100% - 100px);">
                            <nav style="background: white;" class="nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="active {{ @Request::is('dashboard') ? 'active':''}}" style="height: 120px;" class="p-3"><a href="{{ url('dashboard') }}"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart fa-3x"></i> DASHBOARD</a></li>
                                    <li class="{{ @Request::is('tasks') ? 'active':''}}" style="height: 120px;" class="p-3"><a href="{{ url('tasks') }}" class="menu_a"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-3x"></i> Register Form</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div clas="col-11" style="background:lightcyan;width: 89%;float:left;height:calc(100% - 100px);">
                            <div class="p-4"> 
                               
                               Display location of the selected form through the menu
                                
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

How do I do this? I think I can do it with @include, but how?

Comment: My problem is that the selected page is not displayed in front<div> and it is displayed in the new page